# "Connection refused" on Laravel with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, migration, laravel-artisan, seed

I'm using Laravel with Docker, and when I run the romando "`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`", laravel does all the migrations, starts the seeds that come before the one with the problem, and if this seed takes a while slightly larger, Laravel simply cuts the migration and returns "`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`"

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    # image project
    app:
        container_name: web-app
        build:
            args:
                user: rokpixel
                uid: 1000
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: web-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on: 
            - redis
        networks: 
            - backend
    
    # nginx
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes: 
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./.docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks: 
            - backend

    # db mysql
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mariadb:latest
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes: 
            - ./.docker/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        networks: 
            - backend

    # queue
    queue:
        container_name: queue
        image: m2all/web-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: "php artisan queue:work"
        volumes: 
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on: 
            - redis
            - app
        networks: 
            - backend

    # redis
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        networks: 
            - backend

networks: 
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM php:8.1.1-fpm

# Arguments
ARG user=rockpixel
ARG uid=1000

ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    mbstring \
    exif \
    pcntl \
    bcmath \
    zip \
    sockets

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Install redis
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user

# Copy your files
# COPY . .
```

First migration: normal execution

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStatesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create(
            'states',
            function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();

                $table->string('name', 255)
                    ->nullable(false);

                $table->string('initials', 2)
                    ->nullable(true);

                $table->unsignedInteger('iso')
                    ->nullable(true);

                $table->timestamp('created_at')
                    ->nullable(false)
                    ->useCurrent();

                $table->timestamp('updated_at')
                    ->nullable(false)
                    ->useCurrent()
                    ->useCurrentOnUpdate();

                $table->softDeletes();
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('states');
    }
}
```

Second migration: Normal execution

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCitiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

        Schema::create(
            'cities',
            function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();

                $table->foreignId('state_id')
                    ->unsigned()
                    ->nullable(false)
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->constrained('states');

                $table->string('name', 255)
                    ->nullable(false);

                $table->unsignedInteger('iso')
                    ->nullable(true);

                $table->timestamp('created_at')
                    ->nullable(false)
                    ->useCurrent();

                $table->timestamp('updated_at')
                    ->nullable(false)
                    ->useCurrent()
                    ->useCurrentOnUpdate();

                $table->softDeletes();
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cities');
    }
}
```

First Seed: normal execution

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\State;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class CitySeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $states = State::orderBy('name')->get();
        
        foreach($states as $state){
            $apiCities = Http::get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/'.$state->initials.'/municipios');

            foreach($apiCities->json() as $city){
                City::create([
                    'state_id'=>$state->id,
                    'name'=>$city['nome'],
                    'iso'=>$city['id'],
                ]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Second seed: crashes

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\State;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class CitySeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $states = State::orderBy('name')->get();
        
        foreach($states as $state){
            $apiCities = Http::get('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/'.$state->initials.'/municipios');

            foreach($apiCities->json() as $city){
                City::create([
                    'state_id'=>$state->id,
                    'name'=>$city['nome'],
                    'iso'=>$city['id'],
                ]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error: always in the same location

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into `cities` (`state_id`, `name`, `iso`) values (16, Itajuípe, 2915502))
```

Comment: I'm migrating from a mac environment to a windows environment.
This error is happening in the windows environment.
I tested the exact SAME code on mac, and it passed.
Are there any limitations of docker for windows that I don't know about?

Comment: Solved changing mariadb:latest to mariadb:10.3.16